# Writing and Importing Data Modules to Python

Tags: python, function, module, python-import

Is it possible to import a custom module to python, a module containing only data?

What I wish to do is import a data module and then write a function whose input searches the module for data matching the input parameters.

The output of the function would be any data from the module that matches the input parameters.

Ideally it would be something following the design of:

import module

input:(match function parameters with data from module)

output:(print(data from module that matches input parameters)

If anything can be coded to accomplish this, or if anyone has any ideas how to attempt someone like this, I would be grateful for input!

Comment: instead of trying to import module you should try to read a file? Check out [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) .

Comment: I am trying to design a screener to read a file of some kind and select and display matches. Is 'open' still applicable, or is there a better way for python to complete the above action?

Comment: Data is usually stored in files specifically intended for that purpose. Many generic data file types exist, e.g. 'comma-separated files', JSON, XML, etc. Databases can of course also be used. To get started, look at the module `csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Importing a module is effectively going to execute the python in the module at the time of import. So, you could hard code the definition of python objects such as strings, lists, dictionaries, etc in a module and then import the module when you want to access the data via the objects.

That said, it's worth thinking about if hard coding data into a module is really the way you want to go here. As others have pointed out in comments, files containing data formatted as csv, plaintext, json, xml, base64, etc. are more concise and portable. I'd dare say using such files, not modules, feels more Pythonic to me, ironically.

One nice thing about files is you can control how much of a file you stream into memory at a time for processing. That can be critical of you're dealing with lots of data in massive files.